# SQL. How should i write NOT LIKE statement

Tags: sql

```
SELECT       *
FROM            [Table]
WHERE        (Izdava NOT LIKE NULL)
```

// how to check if  Izdava is not  NULL

Comment: which sql database?? I think the tag asp.net is useless, since this is an SQL problem..

Comment: what about: Izdava  is not null

Comment: @Tony - you were so close, especially when you consider your comment had the correct syntax! :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE Izdava IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE (Izdava IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you want.

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table] 
WHERE Izdara Is Not NULL
```

Information about [NULL values from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504.aspx):

> Following is information about nulls:
>
> To test for null values in a query, use IS NULL or IS NOT NULL in the
>   WHERE clause.

Answer (score 5):

LIKE NULL is meaningless.  It doesn't make sense.  [LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28SQL.110%29.aspx) is used for comparing a partial string using wildcards, or a complete string without wildcards.

Depending on the RDBMS you want NOT IS NULL,

```
SELECT * FROM [Table] WHERE (NOT Izdava IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are checking for not null, dont use the like clause. Just write

```
select * from tablename where columnmame is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's MSSQL or Oracle then do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Table]
WHERE Izdava IS NOT NULL
```